# Linq filtering db records using Where (string.Contains("string array instead of single string") )

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using ASP .Net MVC, and I would like to filter my DB result set, until now I've been using this method:

```
var auctions = from o in db.auctions select o;
```

And I'd check if user passed some pattern (searchName) from client form so result set would be filtered:

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchName))
 {
 auctions = auctions.Where(a => a.product_name.Contains(searchName));
 }
```

That's fine if I want to check if product name contains single string variable, but I would need to check if product name contains ANY of array's strings passed as string from client's form and split with blank char something like this:

```
string[] words = searchName.Split(' ');
auctions = auctions.Where(a => a.product_name.Contains(anyStringInArrayWords));
```

How could I end up with this **anyStringInArrayWords** lambda impression sent to auctions.Where()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite the where condition statement bit differently.

```
auctions = auctions.Where(a => words.Contains(a.product_name));
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but here's example I'm not sure if I set correct question, example my auction name is: Test Auction Case, and i want when i type in searchName: Test Case to get this auction after filter.

Answer (score 0):

You may use  .Any extension method to obtain your result.

```
var q= auctions.Any(item => words.Any( word=> item.ProductName.Contains(word))
```

**Written by mobile and not tested**

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ***Hakunamatata***, in case if you are looking for case insensitive search `Contains` is overloaded to accepts `IEqualityComparer`. So you could perform case insensitive search using...

```
auctions = auctions.Where(a => words.Contains(a.product_name, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```